# Trouble linking HTML login code with apps.py Python code with Flask

Tags: python, html, sql, flask

I have this code which runs in the navbar, it's meant to implement a login/registration form but without leaving the home page, its a toggler with a data-target="#login-form":

```html
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-form" class="c-btn-border-opacity-04 c-btn btn-no-focus c-btn-header btn btn-sm c-btn-border-1x c-btn-dark c-btn-circle c-btn-uppercase c-btn-sbold"><i class="icon-user"></i> Sign In</a>
```

How do I change the @app.route so that it targets the login-form that's implemented within the home page? Python code used:

```js
@app.route('/')
def home():
    # Check if user is loggedin
    if 'loggedin' in session:
    
        # User is loggedin show them the home page
        return render_template('home.html', username=session['username'])
    # User is not loggedin redirect to login page
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
 
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
   
    # Check if "username" and "password" POST requests exist (user submitted form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        print(password)
 
        # Check if account exists using MySQL
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s', (username,))
        # Fetch one record and return result
        account = cursor.fetchone()
 
        if account:
            password_rs = account['password']
            print(password_rs)
            # If account exists in users table in out database
            if check_password_hash(password_rs, password):
                # Create session data, we can access this data in other routes
                session['loggedin'] = True
                session['id'] = account['id']
                session['username'] = account['username']
                # Redirect to home page
                return redirect(url_for('home'))
            else:
                # Account doesnt exist or username/password incorrect
                flash('Incorrect username/password')
        else:
            # Account doesnt exist or username/password incorrect
            flash('Incorrect username/password')
 
    return render_template('home.html')
```

```html
<div class="modal fade c-content-login-form" id="login-form" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content c-square">
            <div class="modal-header c-no-border">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3 class="c-font-24 c-font-sbold">Good Afternoon!</h3>
                <p>Let's make today a great day!</p>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group" method="post">
                        <label for="username" class="hide">Username</label>
                        <input type="username" class="form-control input-lg c-square" name="username"  id="username" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="hide">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg c-square" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="c-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="login-rememberme" class="c-check">
                            <label for="login-rememberme" class="c-font-thin c-font-17">
                                <span></span>
                                <span class="check"></span>
                                <span class="box"></span>
                                Remember Me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="form-control btn btn-success btn c-theme-btn btn-md c-btn-uppercase c-btn-bold c-btn-square c-btn-login" name="">Login</input>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forget-password-form" data-dismiss="modal" class="c-btn-forgot">Forgot Your Password ?</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="c-content-divider c-divider-sm c-icon-bg c-bg-grey c-margin-b-20">
                            <span>or signup with</span>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="c-content-list-adjusted">
                            <li>
                                <a class="btn btn-block c-btn-square btn-social btn-twitter">
                                  <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                  Twitter
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="btn btn-block c-btn-square btn-social btn-facebook">
                                  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                  Facebook
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="btn btn-block c-btn-square btn-social btn-google">
                                  <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
                                  Google
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I understand linking specific pages but what if it isn't exactly a page you want to link

Comment: it seems to be as simple as: `<form method="POST" action="">` which You haven't added

Comment: You already have a submit thing in that form so all You need really is to add what I described above

Comment: @Matiiss would this be correct, where the <form> opening is, I changed it to <form method="POST" actions="">

Comment: that is kinda what I said, tho I don't think in this case the `action` argument is necessary, it should work however since You have that submit button of `type="submit"` so that is what should post the form to the same route

Comment: I added that but it does nothing, I still have @app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login(): in my apps.py and when I try to run it on flask  I get this error [21/Jul/2021 14:31:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -

Comment: 302 response means that the resource is temporarily moved or sth like that, which is interesting, I will try to recreate this

Comment: @Matiiss I changed it to @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home(): and I get TypeError
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException, my minds about to explode lol, if you're available to assist me with this project I'll be happy to even pay for some help and I can send you the full code

Comment: I could actually try helping with the full project but in that case not through SO, otherwise I have posted an answer with my approach to this one-route two-part thingy

Answer (score 0):

You already have the navbar and the modal form there. Now you need some javascript that makes the link toggle the modal box visibility.
And also some javascript that intercepts the form submission, prevents it from loading another page, grabs the form data, and posts it to the flask endpoint. Please lookup `javascript fetch() post data`.

Edit: please check Matiiss comment below. It seems Bootstrap already provides the js code you need.

Comment: from the look of things, it seems that OP is using Bootstrap templates, meaning that the simplest thing to do would be to just copy the modal template from the Bootstrap webpage and use that (also copy js parts from the Bootstrap starter template) (oh and then simply create an anchor tag inside that modal template and use `url_for` for the endpoint? route? basically link it to where needed)

Comment: @Matiiss I am so confused I'm sorry, the template I'm using isn't from a specific website i've had it for some time now so I wouldn't know where to find, Is there anything I can Youtube to get a better understanding? I don't want to risk overcomplicating my current project, which has already been overcomplicated

Comment: @Matiis I have all of that already, I have the bootstrap.min.css added I have all the Js added, i dont think you've understand my original question. If you look at the apps.py code I posted you can see "@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():" however I am not using a /login page, same goes for /register, I am only using a data-target="#login-form" & data-target="#signup-form", how do I implement this into my apps.py, my problem is not with bootstrap.

Comment: isn't it possible to put the form inside the modal, then just post request back to the same route?

Comment: @Matiiss its inside the modal - <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-form" but how would i post request back to that route is my ultimate question

Comment: @BitcoinGetta I already added a comment under Your question

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach to have a login forma and home page on the same route (could probably use two templates but this works too):

The main file:

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_key_'
user_logged_in = False


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[InputRequired()])
    password = StringField('Password', validators=[InputRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Login')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    global user_logged_in
    if user_logged_in:
        return render_template('home.html', logged_in=user_logged_in)
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            user_logged_in = True
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        return render_template('home.html', logged_in=user_logged_in, form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Obviously you need to use your user login validation, this is just to for testing (`logged_in` variable)
(Also I spent like 20 min trying to figure out why I couldn't submit form and it was because I didn't include `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` in my form)

The template (super simple):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>

{% if logged_in %}

<h1>You are logged in</h1>
<p>{{ logged_in }}</p>

{% else %}

<form action="{{ url_for('home') }}" method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div>
        {{ form.username.label }}
        {{ form.username }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form.password.label }}
        {{ form.password }}
    </div>
    {{ form.submit }}
</form>

<p>{{ logged_in }}</p>

{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

Basically You check if user is logged in and then just simply pass that variable to the template and there is a huge if statement, I should tho point out that using a modal in this case is not the best idea, you have to just show completely only the login part otherwise someone may open DevTools and just delete that modal and gain accesss to the home page

If You have any questions, ask

Comment: I appreciate this, but i've tried implementing it within my code without changing the visuals of the frontend and it's running a few errors, can i get in touch with you on discord? i'm not too familiar with using these forums without spamming it

Comment: I guess you could get in touch, here is my dc: Matiiss#5629